# How to draw text on captured image?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Hi I am trying to add text on a captured image using the code below and after that I want to save that text draw image in my device internal storage with a separate folder.

But using my below code, the folder is not showing in the internal storage.

Can some one help me please what did I do wrong?

### code:-

```
 /**
     * onCaptureImageResult
     *
     * @param
     */
    private void onCaptureImageResult() {

        try {
            File shopImageFile = new File(Utilities.getRealPathFromURI(imageUri, this));
            Bitmap thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("" + shopImageFile),
                    100, 100, true);
            saveImage(thumbnail);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * saveImage
     */
    private void saveImage(Bitmap originalBitmap) {

        //File myDir = new File("/sdcard/saved_images");
        //myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        // String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        ContextWrapper wrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        //File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        File file = wrapper.getDir("Images", MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // NEWLY ADDED CODE STARTS HERE [
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(originalBitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED); // Text Color
            paint.setStrokeWidth(12); // Text Size
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); // Text Overlapping Pattern
            // some more settings...

            canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            canvas.drawText("Testing...", 100, 100, paint);
            // NEWLY ADDED CODE ENDS HERE ]

            originalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: use frame layout add text view on picture and then take screenshot of that whole layout .?

Comment: can you please help me with some code

Comment: are you successfully capturing picture and displaying it.?

Comment: yes i captured the picture but directory not showing in internal storage

Comment: first store that picture in your device by using permission write to external storage and then get that images uri and display that image in imageview

Comment: after capture have to show text on it and save in seperate folder thats what i want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168634/discussion-between-atif-abbasi-and-krish).

Answer (score 0):

Dear use this [library](https://github.com/Tengio/android-graffiti) to draw text on captured image.

```
compile('com.tengio.android:graffiti:latest_version')
```

And open image like this

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(UriUtil.LOCAL_RESOURCE_SCHEME)
                .path(image path)
                .build();
```